# lavaan - measurement Invariance - partial metric model

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, metric, equivalence, lavaan

I have used the measurementInvarianceCat() function to conduct Measurement Invariance Multigroup Confirmatory Factor Analyses (MGCFA). The output is the following:

```
> measurementInvarianceCat(model3, data = sub1, parameterization = "theta", estimator = "wlsmv",
+                          ordered = c("V34", "V35", "V36", "V52", "V53", "V54", "V37", "V38",
+                                      "V39", "V40"),
+                          group = "SEX")

Measurement invariance models:

Model 1 : fit.configural
Model 2 : fit.loadings
Model 3 : fit.thresholds
Model 4 : fit.means

Scaled Chi Square Difference Test (method = "satorra.bentler.2001")

                Df AIC BIC  Chisq Chisq diff Df diff Pr(>Chisq)    
fit.configural  76         2043.2                                  
fit.loadings    83         2226.2     199.30       7  < 2.2e-16 ***
fit.thresholds 110         2844.9     620.88      27  < 2.2e-16 ***
fit.means      113         3391.0      43.04       3  2.413e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Fit measures:

```
               cfi.scaled rmsea.scaled cfi.scaled.delta rmsea.scaled.delta
fit.configural      0.979        0.053               NA                 NA
fit.loadings        0.977        0.052            0.002              0.000
fit.thresholds      0.972        0.050            0.005              0.002
fit.means           0.976        0.046            0.003              0.004
```

From this i conclude that the null hypothesis that the loadings and intercepts are exactly equal is rejected. Therefore the intercepts and probably the loading should not be constrained to be equal across genders. To find out whicht items should be set free i have used the i have used the function lavTestScore():

> lavTestScore(partial, cumulative = T, epc = TRUE)
>   $test

total score test:

test      X2 df p.value
1 score 113.955  6       0

$uni

```
univariate score tests:

    lhs op    rhs     X2 df p.value
1  .p2. ==  .p95.  1.219  1   0.270
2  .p5. ==  .p98.  7.821  1   0.005
3  .p6. ==  .p99.  1.370  1   0.242
4  .p8. == .p101. 52.712  1   0.000
5  .p9. == .p102. 76.400  1   0.000
6 .p10. == .p103.  1.049  1   0.306

$cumulative

cumulative score tests:

    lhs op    rhs      X2 df p.value
1  .p2. ==  .p95.  76.400  1       0
2  .p5. ==  .p98.  97.282  2       0
3  .p6. ==  .p99. 105.107  3       0
4  .p8. == .p101. 112.698  4       0
5  .p9. == .p102. 113.924  5       0
6 .p10. == .p103. 113.955  6       0

$epc
```

But this is where is struggle. What is .p95? regarding my final model summary table the highest one i have is .p10. How should this part of the output be interpreted?

Anyhow from the lavTestScore() i have chosen a constrained that had epc over 0.1 and an sensible epv. Only 2 parameters had epc larger tha 0.1 (only part of the output shown):

expected parameter changes (epc) and expected parameter values (epv):

```
                lhs  op         rhs group free label plabel    est    epc    epv
```

3   fullfilment  =~         V36     1    2  .p3.   .p3.  1.326  0.100  1.426
 9    experience  =~         V39     1    6  .p9.   .p9.  1.214  0.123  1.337

So i figured i would free "experience =~ V39" then evaluate partial metric model:

```
partial <- sem(model3, data = sub1,
               ordered = c("V34", "V35", "V36", "V52", "V53", "V54", "V38", "V37",
                           "V39", "V40"), estimator = "WLSM",
               group = "SEX",
               group.equal = c("loadings"),
               group.partial = c("experience =~ V37"))
summary(partial, standardized = T, fit.measures = T)
```

When i compared the partial and metric model chi-square was still significant:

```
> lavTestLRT(metric, partial)
Scaled Chi Square Difference Test (method = "satorra.bentler.2001")

        Df AIC BIC  Chisq Chisq diff Df diff Pr(>Chisq)    
partial 82         2107.3                                  
metric  83         2184.6     83.183       1  < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

so I run the lavTestScore():

```
3   fullfilment  =~         V36     1    2  .p3.   .p3.  1.326  0.100  1.426
8    experience  =~         V37     1    5  .p8.   .p8.  1.748 -0.110  1.639
```

and the model again, but with 2 items free by setting:

```
   group.partial = c("experience =~ V39",
                     "experience =~ V37"))
```

and i repreated the process of running lavTestScore(), choosing item with epc greater than 0.1 and including that item in my group.partial and running the model. I only needed to free 3 item in order to obtain lavTestScore() with no more epc larger than 0.1.

```
> lavTestLRT(metric, partial)
Scaled Chi Square Difference Test (method = "satorra.bentler.2001")

        Df AIC BIC  Chisq Chisq diff Df diff Pr(>Chisq)    
partial 82         2107.3                                  
metric  83         2184.6     83.183       1  < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> lavTestLRT(metric, partial2)
Scaled Chi Square Difference Test (method = "satorra.bentler.2001")

         Df AIC BIC  Chisq Chisq diff Df diff Pr(>Chisq)    
partial2 81         2089.0                                  
metric   83         2184.6     103.15       2  < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> lavTestLRT(metric, partial3)
Scaled Chi Square Difference Test (method = "satorra.bentler.2001")

             Df AIC BIC  Chisq Chisq diff Df diff Pr(>Chisq)    
    partial3 80         2060.8                                  
    metric   83         2184.6     121.07       3  < 2.2e-16 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

the chi-square is always significant. i have then compared the global fit findings:

```
> fitMeasures(partial, selected)
   chisq       df    rmsea      cfi      tli 
2107.337   82.000    0.047    0.988    0.983 
> fitMeasures(partial2, selected)
   chisq       df    rmsea      cfi      tli 
2089.020   81.000    0.047    0.988    0.983 
> fitMeasures(partial3, selected)
   chisq       df    rmsea      cfi      tli 
2060.802   80.000    0.047    0.988    0.983
```

- **How can I interpret these finding?**
- **What are the implications for the measurement invariance and my partial petric model?**
- **Is it reasonable to say that no latent mean comparisson is possible? Does it mean that my model is bad?**

Any constructive input would be highly appriciated. Thanks

Comment: Your question is long and complex, and contains multiple questions - that might be why it hasn't had an answer yet. For Q1: How have you interpreted them? I don't want to describe something you already know. For Q2: I've got to read and understand all of your output - can you describe it? Q3 is a much more general question.  I would ask each one on its own.

Comment: @Jeremy Miles, thanks for the advice.  have simplified the question and re-posted it here [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285070/measurementinvariancecat-procedure-and-interpretation-lavaan]