# measurementInvarianceCat() - procedure and interpretation - lavaan

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, equivalence, lavaan

I have identified that sequentially constraining my models I have obtained significant p-value for each.

```
> measurementInvarianceCat(model3, data = sub1, parameterization = "theta", estimator = "wlsmv",
+                          ordered = c("V34", "V35", "V36", "V52", "V53", "V54", "V37", "V38",
+                                      "V39", "V40"),
+                          group = "SEX")

Measurement invariance models:

Model 1 : fit.configural
Model 2 : fit.loadings
Model 3 : fit.thresholds
Model 4 : fit.means

Scaled Chi Square Difference Test (method = "satorra.bentler.2001")

                Df AIC BIC  Chisq Chisq diff Df diff Pr(>Chisq)    
fit.configural  76         2043.2                                  
fit.loadings    83         2226.2     199.30       7  < 2.2e-16 ***
fit.thresholds 110         2844.9     620.88      27  < 2.2e-16 ***
fit.means      113         3391.0      43.04       3  2.413e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

This means that the less restricted model expains the data better. Therefore I can say that constraining all loadings equal is not appropriate here, there are some loading that are significantly different between the groups ( in my case males vs. females). To find out which loading cause this I have used the > `lavTestScore()` which is whewre I run into my problem:

The rule of thumb is suppposed to be to free parameters with `epc` larger than 0.1. I have removed these parameters one by one, until no more item with `epc` >0.1 were left - i have freed 3 items. My final model is then:

```
partial <- sem(model3, data = sub1,
               ordered = c("V34", "V35", "V36", "V52", "V53", "V54", "V38", "V37",
                           "V39", "V40"), estimator = "WLSM",
               group = "SEX",
               group.equal = c("loadings"),
               group.partial = c("experience =~ V37",     # partial
                                 "experience =~ V39",     # partial2
                                 "experience =~ V37"))    # partial3
```

Despite of not having anymore items that are advised to be freed regarding the `lavTestScore()` the `lavTestLRT()` still indicated that the difference between the less constrained model and my partial metric model is significant (`Pr(>Chisq) = < 2.2e-16 ***`), meaning that the less restricted model explains the data better.

i have compared the `CFI` and `TLI` also:

```
> fitMeasures(partial, selected)
   chisq       df    rmsea      cfi      tli 
2107.337   82.000    0.047    0.988    0.983 
> fitMeasures(partial2, selected)
   chisq       df    rmsea      cfi      tli 
2089.020   81.000    0.047    0.988    0.983 
> fitMeasures(partial3, selected)
   chisq       df    rmsea      cfi      tli 
2060.802   80.000    0.047    0.988    0.983
```

The fit doesnt seem to improve between the different partial models. I am not sure what this means. I would interpret such that: the partial metric equivalence does not significantly improve the model, therefore the latent means between the factor loading between the genders connaot be compared. the differences between the factor loading between the genders are not significant enough to improve the overll fit of the model.

**Should i consider my configural model fit as the final best fitting model for my data and interpret the results?**